# comparison counter on binary search

Tags: java, binary-search

So, I have a binary search code (not mine) and I don't know how to put a counter on how many comparisons it made. 
The elements are entered then sorted.
Then this codes comes after.

```
    System.out.println("\nEnter value to find");
    num_search = in.nextInt();

    first  = 0;
    last   = n - 1;
    middle = (first + last)/2; 

    while( first <= last )
    { 
      if ( a[middle] < num_search )
        first = middle + 1;    
      else if ( a[middle] == num_search )
     {
       System.out.println(num_search + " found at location " + (middle + 1) + ".");
          System.out.println("Counter = " + (ctr + middle));
        break;
      }
      else
     last = middle - 1;

      middle = (first + last)/2;
    }
    if (first > last)
  System.out.println(num_search + " isn't present in the list.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increment count like this:

```
int count = 0;
while( first <= last )
{ 
  if ( a[middle] < num_search ) {
    count+= 1;
    first = middle + 1;  
  }  
  else if ( a[middle] == num_search )
 {
   count+= 2;
   System.out.println(num_search + " found at location " + (middle + 1) + ".");
    break;
  }
  else {
      count+= 3;
     last = middle - 1;
 }

  middle = (first + last)/2;
}
System.out.println("Counter = " + count);
```

Comment: It still wont work with more than 7 elements . But thanks!

Comment: Why not? Can you explain?

Comment: Also, we can chane the `count+=3` to `count+=2` in the `else` block since there's no comparison there.

Comment: 1st part of code
public class my_version_binary_search
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int c, first, last, middle, n, num_search, temp, ctr=0;
 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter no. of elements: ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter elements: ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

Comment: 2nd part                //SORTING
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) 
                {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
                System.out.print("Sorted Order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.print(a[n - 1]);

Comment: Okay but only the last part concerns this question right?

Comment: when I used the code you gave me, the counter does not count correctly. when I enter  3 elements[1,2,3],(then I chose to locate number 2) instead of counting only 2 for counter it says 5

Comment: yes, just the last part, I'm sorry I'm new at programming and in this site. T.T

Comment: @reveberces Don't post code to clarify the question in a comment. **Edit** the question and clarify it there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply increment the value of `ctr` for all the three cases.
Make sure you have initialized the `ctr` with `0`;

```
while( first <= last )
    { 
      if ( a[middle] < num_search )
        {first = middle + 1;
        ctr++; //<----increment the count by 1
        }
      else if ( a[middle] == num_search )
     {
       ctr++; //<----increment the count by 1
       System.out.println(num_search + " found at location " + (middle + 1) + ".");
       System.out.println("Counter = " + ctr); //<-----add 1 to result
       break;
      }
      else
      {last = middle - 1;
      ctr++; //<----increment the count by 1
      }

      middle = (first + last)/2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        System.out.println(num_search + " isn't present in the list.\n");
```